# JS document.querySelector заменяет полностью textarea

Tags: javascript

Есть метод

```
onclick='document.querySelector("textarea[name=text]").value="<b>Текст</b>"'
```

Но он полностью заменяет все что есть в **textarea** как сделать чтобы он добавлял просто к уже существующему тексту?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let text = document.querySelector("textarea[name=text]")
let add = (str) => text.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', str)
add("<b>Текст</b>")
add("<b>Текст</b>")
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: У меня есть кнопка которая выполняет это, я нажимаю на одну кнопку - он добавляет, на вторую он тупо заменяет все. Ваш пример мне не поможет

Answer (score 0):

Дайте примеры как работают кнопки у вас. Если сейчас на кнопку будете вызывать add из примера выше. Все будет работать.

```js
let text = document.querySelector("textarea[name=text]")
let add = (str) => text.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', str)
add("<b>Текст</b>")
add("<b>Текст</b>")

addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  add("Добавлен новый текст")
})
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="butt-add"> Добавить текст</button>
```

Comment: А как сделать две допустим кнопки? я просто в JS не шарю.

Comment: А что кнопки эти делать должны? Одна текст добавляет, а вторая?